# Назначить переменную в smarty

Tags: php, smarty

Код ниже выводит значение:

```
$description = qarray('SELECT description FROM '.PREF.'cat_description WHERE cat='.$main_id); 
if($description) echo $description['description'];
```

Как в smarty вывести переменную, скажем назовем ее: {%$cat_description%}

Comment: а сложность то что именно вызывает? как вы передаете эти данные в смарти, как выводите в шаблоне?

Comment: Не получается вывести

Comment: в приведенном код смарти не фигурирует. как можно вам помочь, если тут нет собственно проблемы самой?